# Identifying a Saint on a Greek Orthodox icon?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, saint, iconography, hagiography, identify-this

I got this icon from Greece, however I was not able to identify the Saint. Could anyone help?

[image: unknown saint]

Answer (score 7):

The Greek lettering is (in modern script) Ό Άγιος Παΐσιος ὁ Ἁγιορείτης — Saint Paisios of Mount Athos.

Wikipedia has an [article on him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paisios_of_Mount_Athos).

> He was  born Arsenios Eznepidis (1924–1994), was a well-known Greek Eastern Orthodox ascetic from Mount Athos, who originated from Pharasa, Cappadocia. He was respected for his spiritual guidance and ascetic life and many people worldwide highly venerate Elder Paisios, especially in Greece and in Russia.
>
> Venerable Elder Paisios was canonized on 13 January 2015 by the Holy Synod of the Ecumenical Patriarchate, and the church commemorates his feast day on July 12.
>
> The Holy Synod of the Russian Orthodox Church decided at its meeting of May 5, 2015 also to add the name of the Venerable Paisios of Mount Athos to the Menology of the Russian Orthodox Church, establishing his feast day on June 29/July 12, following the Menology of the Orthodox Church of Constantinople.

Answer (score 1):

This icon is of Saint Paisios of mount Athos (Ο Αγιος Παισιος). This particular icon has him in the traditional orthodox garb while others I've seen also have him in very simply clothing with a beanie.

You can read more about him on the [Orthodox Wiki](https://orthodoxwiki.org/Paisios_of_Mount_Athos). There's also a good book regarding his life from [Hieromonk Isaac](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20443622-elder-paisios-of-mount-athos) as well as a [TV show on MegaTV](https://www.megatv.com/tag/agios-paisios/).

> Our venerable and God-bearing Father Paisios of Mount Athos or Paisios
> the New, of the Holy Mountain (July 25, 1924 – July 12, 1994), also
> known as Elder Paisios (Greek: Γέροντας Παΐσιος ο Αγιορείτης), was a
> monastic of Mount Athos. An ascetic, he was known by his visitors for
> his gentle manner and acceptance of those who came to receive his
> advice, counsel, and blessing. His words of counsel continue to be
> published. Elder Paisios was canonized on January 13, 2015, by the
> Holy and Sacred Synod of the Ecumenical Patriarchate of
> Constantinople. The Church commemorates St. Paisios on July 12.